# Boolean Calculator How to check user input using stacks c++

Tags: c++, stack, boolean, calculator

im making a calculator where the user inputs can input <,>,<=,>=,&&,||,
==,! ie (2>3) or (2>3)&&(5<3) etc. and it calculates it to true or false. The problem is how can i go by using the expressions such as "<=,>=" using an if else statement. The only operations that work are "<" and ">".
This is the function that checks if the input matches an operation

```
  void evalute_stack_tops(std::stack<double>& numbers, std::stack<char>& operations){

      double operand1,operand2;


      operand2= numbers.top();
      numbers.pop();
      operand1= numbers.top();
      numbers.pop();


if(operations.top()=='<')
 {

    numbers.push(operand1<operand2);

 }
else if (operations.top()=='>')
 {

    numbers.push(operand1>operand2);


 }

else if(operations.top()=='>='){

    numbers.push(operand1 >= operand2);
}





}
```

Comment: Your stack is of single characters, that's why only the single character value comparisons work. Try making a stack of `std::string`s (or `char *`) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`operations` is a `stack<char>` i.e. a stack of characters.  So you can access only one char at a time.

### How to solve it ? alternative 1:

You need to extend your `if` block to check if `'>'` or `'<'` is by any chance followed by an `'='` or not.

Example:

```
...
if(operations.top()=='<') {
    operations.pop(); 
    if (operations.top()=='=') {
        numbers.push(operand1<=operand2);
        operations.pop(); 
    }
    else numbers.push(operand1<operand2); // and let top of op stack unchanged
 }
```

I don't know how you are pushing the operations.  I've assumed that `">="` would be pushed in reverse order, so first the `'='` and then the `'>'`.  If you did it the other way round, you'd have to adapt.

### How to solve it ? Alternative 2

Alternatively you could consider make `operations` a `std::stack<std::string>` and push the string containing the full operator (one or two chars) instead of char by char.

This could be easier:  you just shouldn't forget to put double-quotes instead of single quotes arround the your constants in the *if-expression*

### Important hint

Please note that the single quote is meant to enclose only a single char.  As soon as you have more than one single char, you should consider using double-quotes to show that you mean a string litteral.  And work with std::string instead of char.